# How to use use something like HashMap in PHP?

Tags: php, dictionary, post

I am getting content from another page, it has two variables, `From` and `Body` . Both the variables are strings, I am storing both of them in variables.

```
$number = $_POST['From'];
$body = $_POST['Body'];
```

the `$body` has data like this, `MT 80, SP 30, UP 45` 
I want to make a dictionary or a hashmap of the same. where in `MT` is the key and `80` is its value.

I will be later storing them in the database, so can you please tell me how to do this? I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all split all of the comma separated values into an array

```
$array = preg_split( '/(,\s|,)/', $body);
```

Now we want to separate the sets of letters and numbers (e.g MT and 80).
So we split each of these by the whitespace between them

```
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $temp = explode(" ",$array[$i]);
    $result[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
```

The variable $result will contain the associative array e.g. $result['MT'] = 80; etc

As for the database, I would recommend using PDO(PHP Data Object):

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // Make it show exceptions if something goes wrong
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (key, value) VALUES (:key, :value)");

    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        $query->execute(array(":key"=>$key,":value"=>$value));
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This example is assuming that you will be using mysql. Obviously you will need to replace $servername, $dbname, $username, $password and tableName with the appropriate values.

Comment: How to iterate over this then?

Comment: @MayurTolani `foreach($result as $key => $value){ /* code */ }`

Comment: Sorry I missed the comments I was adding the part about the database. I have put the foreach loop as part of the database code.

Comment: foreach($result as $key => $value){ 
  print $key;
  print $value;
 }

this prints nothing

Comment: Try this:
`$array = preg_split( '/(,\s|,)/', $body);  
$result = array();  
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){  
    
    $temp = explode(" ",$array[$i]);  
    $result[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];  
}  
                  
foreach($result as $key => $value){  
     print $key;  
     print $value;  
}`